# Is there any way to get more top users for a tag?

Tags: discussion, top-users

For each tag one can see a list of top users. For example here is a [list for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers).

Is there any way to get a bigger list may (be with an information about the number of positive answers each of them wrote in last X days)?

Comment: You could maybe start with [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/12927/top-users-per-tag)

Comment: He he :) I read that as "how to make more people a top user in a tag" and came running to see what had been said so far :) But no, its a request for boring statistics.